# Call content of UITextField from different class

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitextfield, uicontainerview

My goal is that I can configure a label from a `UICollectionViewCell` inside a container view.

I have a view controller with an `UICollectionView` and if I double tap one of these cells a container view is opens. This is already working, but I have a `UITextField` inside the `ContainerViewController` which should update the `nameLabel` of the `ItemCell`.

How can I get the text property from the `containerController` to the `ItemCell func changeName()`?

```
class ItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    func changeName() {
        nameLabel.text = containerController.nameField.text
    }
}
```

Obviously this function is not working.

```
var containerController = ContainerController()
class ContainerController: UIViewController {        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you double tap the cell, pass a reference of the tapped cell to the `ContainerController`, then have the `ContainerController` instance call the `changeName` function on the cell. I would recommend mutating the `changeName` function to accept a `String` like so:

```
class ItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    func changeName(newName: String) {
        nameLabel.text = newName
    }

}
```

### **UPDATE FOR AFTER THE CODE WAS GIVEN**

One thing you could do is add a property to your `ContainerController` like so:

```
weak var textCell: ItemCell?
```

Then also change the method in `ItemCell` to take a `String`:

```
func changeName(newName: String) {
    nameLabel.text = newName
}
```

Then in your `handleTap(_:)` method, where you are retrieving the cell and calling `openContainer()`, change it to something like:

```
if let index = indexPath,
    let cell = ItemCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index) as? ItemCell {
    container.textCell = cell
    openContainer()
} else {
    print("Could not find index path or cell")
}
```

Then in your `ContainerController`, once the text is entered call `textCell?.changeName(_:)` with the new text.

**I also want to add** that I do not recommend doing something like this. Ideally, the text the user enters in `ContainerController` would update the data source for the collection view then the app would reload that cell. With the way it is now, as soon as the cell is reused, the text will revert back to what the data source says. Just something to consider.

Comment: I think that would be a bit tricky with my current setup. I provided my ViewController in the edit maybe you could help me.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah your idea is good because as soon your reload something every cell has it's default values again. Do you know a way to bypass that?

Comment: The only way to bypass it would be to never set the text of the cell again, which is ridiculous. That is why setting the cell text as opposed to the data source is not recommended. Also, if this post is the answer, then please accept it as the answer so others can benefit.

Comment: But something else do you recommend another way do this whole thing? You mentioned that there is an easier way for this.

Comment: Yes. Grab the index path of the cell. Then when the user finishes entering text, set the text in the data source at the corresponding index to the text the user entered, then reload the cell at that index path.